# Node.js module won't return the object but does cosole.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a module that search documents inside **`mongodb`**.
When I call the `check_permitions` (with the argument), I get "undefined" return from the function, but the `console.log(rslts[0].faq)` return the right object. What is the problem?

```
var iapp = require('./app');

exports.check_permitions = function(user_id) {
  iapp.website_coll.find({}).where('admins_id').equals(user_id).exec(function(err, rslts) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else if (rslts) {
      console.log(rslts[0].faq);
      return (rslts[0].faq);
    } else if (!rslts) {
      console.log('no r');
      return (rslts[0].faq);
    }
  });
  console.log('top');
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: First, that's an asynchronous function so it won't return exactly when you want it. Second, you're returning from the callback, not from your main function.

Comment: A call (to `console.log`) is not a `return`. And [your callback is asynchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your call here is asynchronous. You need to pass in a callback and then call that callback with the return values.

Updated example:

```
exports.check_permitions = function (user_id, callback) {
    iapp.website_coll.find({}).where('admins_id').equals(user_id).exec(function(err, rslts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err);
        }
        else if (rslts) {
            console.log(rslts[0].faq);
            callback(null, rslts[0].faq);
        }
        else if (!rslts) {
            console.log('no r');
            callback(null, null);
        }
    });
    console.log('top');
};
```

Here's a tutorial on the asynchronous concept in node: http://lostechies.com/johnteague/2012/11/30/node-js-must-know-concepts-asynchrounous/

---

EDIT:
You have to pass in a callback.

Your calling code probably looks something like this:

```
var result = check_permitions(some_user_id);
// do something with result
```

You'll need to update it to this:

```
check_permitions(some_user_id, function(err, result) {
    // do something with result
})
```

I'd recommend learning more about asynchronous javascript code. It doesn't always execute top-down as you'd expect. The point of the callback is that it'll be called *at some arbitrary point* in the future, after the database results have returned, at which point the outer calling code has already finished execution.

Comment: It gives me an error: callback(null, rslts[0].faq); TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Thanks!! now i understand a lot more about the asynchronous concept!